# upgrade bash on M1 but cannot change to the new bash

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, apple-silicon

I installed new bash via `brew`

```bsh
brew install bash
which bash # /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

I have added `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin20.4.0)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

however, in the terminal, I'm still staying in bash3.2.

```bsh
echo ${BASH_VERSION} # still being 3.2.57(1)-release
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is as described by @NobodyNada in the comments. But since he hasn't posted this as an answer for a long time, I paste it here:

`Terminal -> Preferences -> General -> Shells open with` should be set to "Default login shell".

Answer (score 4):

What you've done -should- work.

Might want to verify the contents of `/etc/shells`:

```
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

and retry changing the shell:

```
Scot-MBP:~ sfederman$ chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
Changing shell for sfederman.
Password for sfederman:
chsh: no changes made
```

then testing:

```
Scot-MBP:~ sfederman$ which bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
Scot-MBP:~ sfederman$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
5.1.8(1)-release
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it on MacBook Pro (Apple **M3** Pro) running **Sonoma** 14.3.1:

1. Install bash:

   ```bash
   brew install bash
   ```
2. Change the shell to Homebrew's `bash`:

   ```bash
   sudo chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash "$USER"
   ```

   *As [Ant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196059/398039) pointed out, I had to use `sudo` to avoid this error:*

   ```bash
   chsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/bash: non-standard shell
   ```
3. Create "~/.bash_profile" and add the path to Homebrew:

   ```bash
   eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
   ```
4. Quit `Terminal.app`
5. Reopen `Terminal.app` and confirm that bash is the latest version:

   ```bash
   echo ${BASH_VERSION}
   ```

OPTIONAL:

6. In `Terminal.app`, go to `Settings... > [General]: Shells open with:` and click `Default login shell`.

   *This was a default setting on my OS.*

FYI:

My `/etc/shells` doesn't contain the `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` path.

However my `Terminal.app` does use Homebrew's shell:

```bash
$ which bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
$ echo ${BASH_VERSION}
5.2.26(1)-release
```

Comment: Nice summary. Would recommend to add the shell to /etc/shells though, so it can also be selected in the Advanced Users definition in System Settings.